# Converting buffer to array of strings

Tags: c, winapi

I downloaded text from the edit field to the buffer and I want to convert it to an array of strings. Every string is ending with `%`.

```c
void Converter(HWND hwnd)
{
    int Length = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit) + 1;
    LPSTR data = (LPSTR)malloc(Length);
    char set[500][11];

    GetWindowTextA(hEdit, data, Length);

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    char record[10];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Length, x<500; i++)
    {
        if(data[i]!= '\0' )
            {
            record[y] = data[i];
            y++;
            }
        else if(data[i] == '%')
        {
            strcpy(set[x], record);
            x++;
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    free(data);
}
```

The error message I got:

```
Exception thrown at location 0x00007FF684C91F9B in myproject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading at location 0x000000CBFC8D5DAF.
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see when the error occurs and what state your variables are in just prior to that point? Also your for loop condition is probably not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` (or `WinMain`) and all `#include` directives.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < Length, x<500; i++)
```

Your condition is wrong, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Length && x<500; i++)
```

Also, the `else if` block is never executed, because '%' is not equal to '\0'. This can be fixed by swapping them.

```
if(data[i] == '%')
{
    strcpy(set[x], record);
    x++;
    y = 0;
}
else if(data[i] != '\0')
{
    record[y] = data[i];
    y++;
}
```

The third problem is that the last word in your %-delimited string will not be copied into `set` since there is no percent sign after it.

There is one more bug. You forgot to put a null-terminator at the end of record before copying it, this causes shorter strings to retain letters from previous ones.

```
record[y] = '\0';
strcpy(set[x], record);
```

At this point I recommend using [`strtok`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) from `<string.h>`, and a memory safe programming language like Rust.

Comment: What is the longest string between two percent signs? If it is more than 9 characters (null terminator!), that will cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
char** make_array(_In_ char* buf, _Out_ unsigned* pn)
{
    char* pc = buf;
    unsigned n = 1;
    
    while(pc = strchr(pc, '%')) n++, *pc++ = 0;

    if (char** arr = new char*[n])
    {
        *pn = n;

        char** ppc = arr;
        
        do {
            *ppc++ = buf;
            buf += strlen(buf) + 1;
        } while(--n);

        return arr;
    }

    *pn = 0;
    return 0;
}

void demo()
{
    char buf[] = "1111%2222%33333";
    unsigned n;
    if (char** arr = make_array(buf, &n))
    {
        char** ppc = arr;
        do {
            printf("%s\n", *ppc++);
        } while (--n);
        delete [] arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample code to show strcpy with 2d array is use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   
    char set[500][11];
    
    strcpy(&set[x][0], "a record");

    printf(">> %s", &set[x][0]);
}
```

Output:

```
>> a record
```